# Rails 4, Paperclip on Heroku does not recognize broken image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

having trouble solving problem with pictures on my project.

Summary: Rilas 4 hosted on Heroku using Paerclip with S3

Problem starts with having to use previously used custom uploading logic with S3. picture url looks something like this `/profile_picture/:style_:image_hash`. It works fine with images that are there but with images that are not present paperclip still trying to access image that is not there and the actual link look something like this: `http://s3.amazonaws.com/project/profile_pictures/100h_`.

```
 has_attached_file :picture,
                styles:          { :'53h' => '', :'100h' => '' },
                convert_options: {
                    :'100h' => '-gravity center -thumbnail 165x165^ -extent 165x165',
                    :'53h'  => '-gravity center -thumbnail 45x45^ -extent 45x45'
                },
                path:            'profile_pictures/:style_:filename',
                default_url:     '/images/default-pp-large.jpg'
```

I am guessing that might be because of style inside the actual filename, but i am not sure, eather way `defauly_url` is not working and images all are broken, excluding the ones that are actually there.

Can you help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end i made a monkey pach to paperclip gem. Added this lines to `config/initializers/paperclip.rb`

```
module Paperclip
  class Attachment
    alias_method :original_url, :url

    def url(style_name = default_style, options = {})
      if @instance.public_send("#{@name.to_s}_file_name").blank?
        'default-pp-large.jpg'
      else
        original_url(style_name, options)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm wondring how is the `ID` is not present in the path for the picture, as in this case if 2 differents Pictures with same name it will retrieve the first match as i think, path should be something like:

```
path: 'profile_pictures/:id_:style_:filename'
# OR
path: 'profile_pictures/:id/:style_:filename'
```

not sure if that should be totally solving the problem but that is a part of it.

Comment: i cant do that, because, like i said, migrations are coming with existing s3 files, so changing actual path to file is not an option.